# How can I use a regex to replace a varying number of zeroes with the same number of spaces?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++, fixed-length-record

I'm working with fixed-length field data, and I need to shorten the decimal places of a series of numbers to only two decimal places. It is nothing but zeroes after the decimal, so it's easy enough to write a regex that will trigger on it. The problem is, I need to replace the extra zeroes with spaces. I know I can save a subexpression and recall it in the replacement, but is there a way to count the number of zeroes removed and recall that? I'm just using the regex in Notepad++'s replace window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something that works here.

search string:  `([.]00[ ]*)0`

replace string: `\1`     (There's a space following the 1)

What this does is find the .00, followed by any number of spaces, followed by a zero. It then replaces that with the .00 and the spaces, followed by a space. Each time it is run, it replaces one more of the extra zeroes with a space. It works, but can anyone think of something that only has to be run once? This worked in this case, but I've had other times when I wished regex could count.

Comment: Neat solution, I don't believe there's a way to do what you need in a single line.

Comment: Luckily the most extra zeroes any field had was 4 or 5. If there were a significant number I would have been in trouble :)  Edit: Actually, I guess I could have just had it replace multiple zeroes at once, counting down through powers of two.

Answer (score 1):

> This worked in this case, but I've had other times when I wished regex could count.

Haven't we all wished that at one time or another :)

The only way I've found to do what you need is to use Python's regular expression library, which allows you to specify a function to do the replace, instead of a replace string. So you could make this call on every line in your file:

```
re.sub(search_string, replace_func, line)
```

This is how you would use it:

```
import re
search_string = r'(\.0{2})(0+)'
# this function is called for each match, and returns the replace string
def replace_func(match):
    num_zeroes = len(match.group(2))
    if num_zeroes:
        return match.group(1) + num_zeroes * ' '
    else:
       return ''

for line in ('1234.0', '1234.00', '1234.000', '1234.0000'):
    print re.sub(search_string, zero_replacer, line)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't help you for Notepad++, but if you're interested, I could write up a more complete python script that would read your file and do the work.

Comment: My solution works for now, but if I ever have to do something bigger, I may come back and incorporate yours into a script. Thanks for the offer :)

Comment: There's a python plugin to run python scripts on your Notepad++ code.  Thus, you could make a script with this, run it, and you're golden.  But maybe that's what you were already referring to?

Answer (score 0):

you need to run this in a loop to use the back references correctly:

```
var data = "7.00000000000 5.00000000 8.0 9.000000000000000000000";
var re = /(\.0{0,2})(0*)/;
alert(data.replace(re, RegExp.$1 +RegExp.$2.replace(/0/, 'x')));
```

*edit: first answer collapsed, which is not what the OP wanted.*

Comment: A fixed length field means there must be the same number of characters after the replacement as before. Replacing something with an empty string won't work, which is why I was looking for a way for a regex to know how many characters it found.

Comment: my bad, misread that...updated a little bit...the strategy being to capture the 0's in $2, and run a replace on that group to get your fixed length spaces.

Comment: What language is that? I'm just using the built in regex in Notepad++, not writing it into a program. It does appear that your solution would work if I were coding it, however.

Comment: javascript. notepad++ doesn't appear to allow the quantifiers {0,2}, so I don't think it is even capable of counting.