# How to substitute substring with dynamic number of spaces

Tags: regex, notepad++

I would like to use Notepad++ to substitute the decimal digits of a column of numbers with an equivalent amount of white spaces.

For example, this input (vertical bars are there on purpose)

```
|    1.23|
|  45.678|
|901.2345|
```

would become

```
|    1   |
|  45    |
|901     |
```

Basically, the dot and decimal digits have been substituted with a dynamic number of white spaces: 2+1 spaces for the first row, 3+1 for the second, 4+1 for the third.

I've looked at a few different posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9625698/how-can-i-use-a-regex-to-replace-a-varying-number-of-zeroes-with-the-same-number) and have tried something like: *replace `\.\d+` with `\s+`*, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in notepad++ if I have understanded you well,

Find: `^([ |\d]*)\.|\G\d{1,1}`
Replace with: `$1`     after $1 there is a single `space`

Now it is possible with Notepad++
`Updated answer`

There is a prove with image
[image]

Comment: Your solution eliminates the dot and decimal digits. I want to substitute them with white spaces

Comment: Please see my answer I just updated it, it is working as Desired

Comment: That is what I wanted, thanks :) As a plus, if I had the numbers in the same row, e.g. `|    1.23|  45.678|901.2345|`, how would the regex change? Is it possible to do achieve the result `|    1   |  45    |901     |`?

Comment: @RicS: Multiple numbers in a line works with both of my solutions.

Comment: Then you may use this code  Find: `(\| ?\d+)\.|\G\d{1,1}`     with the same replacement `$1 `

Comment: @HajiRahmatullah That's great! A small correction though: I achieve the expected result with an asterisk in place of the question mark, i.e. `(\| *\d+)\.|\G\d{1,1}`. Thanks again!

Comment: @ Rica  asterisk means,  (zero or more) and question mark means (zero or one) anyway I'm glad you problem is solved... there is no need for both of them,  I added it because your last numbers |091.2345 had no space from pipe, if there is a single space between pipe and 901? Then no need for question mark and asterisk ....

Comment: Yeah, there is need for asterisk because sometimes I have zero spaces from pipe, sometimes one, sometimes more than one. Anyway, thanks for the good solution!

Comment: You got it correct✔  thumbs up★

Answer (score 3):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\.(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?(\d)?`
- Replace with:  `(?1 )(?2 )(?3 )(?4 )`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\.          # a dot
(\d)?       # optional group 1, 1 digit
(\d)?       # optional group 2, 1 digit
(\d)?       # optional group 3, 1 digit
(\d)?       # optional group 4, 1 digit
and so on
```

**Replacement:**

```
            # a space
(?1 )       # if group 1 exists, add a space
(?2 )       # if group 2 exists, add a space
(?3 )       # if group 3 exists, add a space
(?4 )       # if group 4 exists, add a space
and so on
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it does its job when the maximum number of digits is 4. However, is there a way to do it for any number of decimal digits without typing the structure `(?X )` over and over again? I was looking for a more generalized way

Comment: @RicS: Unfortunatly, no. The groups have to be numbered. There can be a solution with a script.

Comment: With a script in Notepad++ or in a programming language such as Python?

Comment: @RicS: Both ;) [You can install python script plugin in Notepad++](https://community.notepad-plus-plus.org/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above).

Comment: @RicS: I've posted another answer with pythonscript plugin.

Comment: switching to Haji's solution since it does not require a Python script, but still I like your solution!

Answer (score 1):

You can run a python script within the PythonScript plugin.

The following will work for any number of digits after the dot.

If it is not yet installed, follow this [guide](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/topic/17256/guide-how-to-install-the-pythonscript-plugin-on-notepad-7-6-3-7-6-4-and-above)

- Create a script (Plugins >> PythonScript >> New Script)
- Copy this code and save the file (for example format.py):

```py
import re
def format(match):
    return " " * len(match.group(1))
editor.rereplace('(\.\d+)', format)
```

- Open the file you want to modify
- Run the script `Plugins >> PythonScript >> Scripts >> format`
- Done

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]